# Crash on keyPressEvent

Tags: c++, qt

I'm creating a program that draws colours then another class checks them and returns true if they match. The whole code of which is in a dialog. colQ is a class that simply stores RGB values and other things; we'll be using these to get the RGBs.

```
colDialog::colDialog(QWidget *parent) // etc..
{
  // initialization code

    colQ.setColor(255, 0, 0); // red
    r_ans = g_ans = b_ans = nullptr;
}
```

I then have a paint event that does the drawing. r1 and br1 are pointers to their respective classes.

```
void Atn_QDialog::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *e)
{
    QPainter painter(this);

    r1 = new QRect(100, 100, 175, 400);
    br1 = new QBrush(QColor(colQ.getR, colQ.getG, colQ.getB));
    painter.fillRect(*r1, *br1);
    painter.drawRect(*r1);

    // other color code
}
```

At this point, I would have a rectangle drawn with the colour red. What I want to do now is have the user press a key (like 1) and then colQ will then check whether the color stored matches the one on the rectangle to which the key is pressed.

```
void colDialog::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *Ev)
{
    if (Ev->key() == Qt::Key_1)
    {
         br1->color().getRgb(r_ans, g_ans, b_ans);
         colQ.answer(*r_ans, *g_ans, *b_ans);

         if (colQ.isCorrect())
              ui->resultlabel->setText("correct!");
         else ui->resultlabel->setText("wrong!"); 
    }

    // other key presses here
    QDialog::keyPressEvent(Ev);
}
```

The bug occurs when I press the '1' key where the code has thus far been implemented. Before, pressing the key responds fine but it doesn't when this code is run. Fyi, colQ has NO Qt code, and ommitting the code thereof still causes my program to crash. What I'm doing here is I want to get the color stored in br of type QBrush*. I passed pointers into getRgb(..) as that was what's asked for. The code crashes effectively on keyPressEvent(Ev); things like ui->resultlabel-~>setText("...") don't cause the program to crash on key presses. It only occurs with the foresaid function calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program crashes here:

```
br1->color().getRgb(r_ans, g_ans, b_ans);
```

`r_ans`, `g_ans` and `b_ans` have to be initialized and memory has to be allocated for those pointers. `QColor::getRgb` doesn't allocate memory for you, it just changes the values and because of that it crashes with segmentation fault/access violation.

Inside the constructor allocate memory for those 3 pointers:

```
colDialog::colDialog(QWidget *parent) // etc..
{
  // initialization code

    colQ.setColor(255, 0, 0); // red
    r_ans = new int;
    g_ans = new int;
    b_ans = new int;
}
```

If you have a `nullptr` and you try to dereference it: `int *p = nullptr; int x = *p;` the program will crash. This is what happens inside `QColor::getRgb`: the 3 pointers are dereferenced in order to change the values they're pointing to and so your application crashes.

Also a horrible you're thing you're doing is:

```
r1 = new QRect(100, 100, 175, 400);
br1 = new QBrush(QColor(colQ.getR, colQ.getG, colQ.getB));
```

inside `paintEvent`. Even if you're releasing the memory somewhere in the `paintEvent` function it's a bad idea to do. Declare `r1` on the stack and initialize it in the constructor, you don't need pointers here. Also, create `br1` on the stack as well. There is no need for pointers and dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: I've initialized r_ans, g_ans and b_ans to nullptr in the constructor. Isn't that enough for the code to work?

Comment: @Vormeph No, you need to allocate memory for them, see my edits.

Comment: At first, it didn't work but I later ceased inline initialization of the pointers and moved the answers to another function. Thanks for your help!

Comment: `r_ans`, `g_ans`, `b_ans` would be better if they weren't pointers, but automatic variables. You can pass them as reference to the `QColor::getColor` method: `br1.color().getRgb(&r_ans, &g_ans, &b_ans);` Remember, don't use pointers unless you have a good reason to do so.